# How to table cell value font color change VBA word? Font.Textcolor not working why?

Tags: vba

Change table cell value font color without using colorindex. But **Font.Textcolor** not working why?.I am using 2013 word.the error comes(Object does not support this action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextColor is Read-Only.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/font-textcolor-property-word

You can use this:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Color = RGB(68, 114, 196)
```